# Android Studio doesn't start on clicking the icon

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio on my Win 8.1 laptop without an error, but when i click on the icon to start, it doesn't start. 
I've added the system variable JAVA_HOME. I also tried adding JDK_HOME and  also the direction on the PATH variable, but nothing happend.
I'm using jdk 1.7.0_40.

At this point I don't know what to do.

Comment: Is there an error you are seeing?

Comment: The shortcut to android studio might be corrupted for w/e reason. Try opening the .exe directly from the directory you installed it. Usually found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin

Comment: I tried that  in my C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin folder  execute studio64.exe and its the same the only thing that opens was the splash screen

Comment: Have you re-checked the JDK_HOME environment variable? Sometiems this could bring this kind of behaviour, maybe your JDK version, are you using 1.7?

Comment: Yes i've checked de JDK_HOME variable.. and nothing happen..I'm using the jdk version 1.7.0_40

Comment: Try Upgrading to JDK version 1.8